# Why does the error of my NN not divergate to zero when my input reveals the result

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

Why does the error of my NN not divergate to zero when my input reveals the result? I always set `input[2]` to the right result, so the NN should set all weights to 0, except this one.

```
from random import random
import numpy
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow import keras

datax = []
datay = []
for i in range(100000):
    input = []
    for j in range(1000):
        input.append(random())
    yval=random()
    # should be found out by the nn that input[2] is always the correct output
    input[2] = yval
    datax.append(input)
    datay.append(yval)
    
datax = numpy.array(datax)
datay = numpy.array(datay)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam())
model.fit(datax, datay, epochs=100, batch_size=32, verbose=1)
```

it oscillates around e-05 but never gets really better than that

```
Epoch 33/100
3125/3125 [==============================] - 4s 1ms/step - loss: 1.2802e-04
Epoch 34/100
3125/3125 [==============================] - 4s 1ms/step - loss: 3.7720e-05
Epoch 35/100
3125/3125 [==============================] - 4s 1ms/step - loss: 4.0858e-05
Epoch 36/100
3125/3125 [==============================] - 4s 1ms/step - loss: 8.5453e-05
Epoch 37/100
3125/3125 [==============================] - 5s 1ms/step - loss: 5.5722e-05
Epoch 38/100
3125/3125 [==============================] - 5s 1ms/step - loss: 3.6459e-05
Epoch 39/100
3125/3125 [==============================] - 5s 1ms/step - loss: 1.3339e-05
Epoch 40/100
3125/3125 [==============================] - 5s 1ms/step - loss: 5.8943e-05
...
Epoch 100/100
3125/3125 [==============================] - 4s 1ms/step - loss: 1.5929e-05
```

Answer (score 0):

The step of the gradient descent method is calculated as gradient multiplied by learning rate. So theoretically - you can not reach minimum of loss function.

Try decaying learning rate though (decaying to zero). If you are lucky - I think it could be possible because of descrete nature of float types.